# Looking to improve current database schema

Tags: database-design, schema

I have recently developed a schema for managing sports-related data, and I would greatly appreciate your opinion on its structure. Additionally, any advice or suggestions you may have for improvement would be invaluable to me.

You can have a digital look of the schema here: https://miro.com/app/board/uXjVPouZAj8=/?share_link_id=229421434910

```
Season:

id (primary key): Unique identifier for a season.
name: Name of the season.
start_date: Start date of the season.
end_date: End date of the season.

__
Competition:

id (primary key): Unique identifier for a competition.
name: Name of the competition.
season_id (foreign key): References the corresponding season for the competition.
category_id (foreign key): References the category (if applicable) for the competition.
matches[] (foreign key): Represents the collection of matches associated with the competition.
teams[] (foreign key): Represents the collection of teams associated with the competition

__
Leaderboard:
id (primary key): Unique identifier for a leaderboard.
competition_id (foreign key): References the corresponding competition for the leaderboard.

__
Teamstats:

id (primary key): Unique identifier for team statistics.
leaderboard_id (foreign key): References the corresponding leaderboard.
team_id (foreign key): References the corresponding team.
wins
draws 
losses 
amesPlayed 
goalsFor 
goalsAgainst 
goalDifference

__
Team:

id (primary key): Unique identifier for a team.
name: Name of the team.
logo: Logo of the team.
country: Country of the team.

__
Match:

id (primary key): Unique identifier for a match.
homeTeam (foreign key): References the home team.
awayTeam (foreign key): References the away team.
homeScore: Score of the home team.
awayScore: Score of the away team.
competition_id (foreign key): References the corresponding competition for the match.
```

Thank you in advance for taking the time to review the schema and provide your feedback. I genuinely appreciate your assistance and expertise.

Comment: Questions seeking opinions are off-topic.  Perhaps you could rephrase your question

Comment: `matches[] (foreign key)` is that an array or a junction table? An array is a really bad idea. `Teamstats` seems pointless, it just duplicates information already available.

Comment: The main idea for `matches` is to have a `many to one relationship` with competitions. As for the `teamstats`, its use is for the leaderboard, to keep track of wins losses etc for each team participating in that particular league / competition